# create. view sql

Tags: mysql, sql, create-view

Hello I am trying to do create view and I am getting a error message saying missing keyword. I have posted my code below:

```
CREATE VIEW DetailsView AS
SELECT NAME, ADDRESS
FROM StudentDetails
WHERE S_ID < 5;
```

Comment: CREATE VIEW CustDetails AS
SELECT NAME, city
FROM customer
WHERE CUSTOMER_ID > 10;

Comment: still isn't working please help

Comment: Which MySQL version? Works fine in both MySQL 5.6 and 8.

Comment: Parsing errors can sometimes be caused by usage of **reserved keywords**, NAME of course being one of them in mySQL even though it's not clear which version you are using. It's best to avoid them when naming columns or objects.
See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-N

Comment: please give the version of Mysql ? `select version() ;`

Comment: please copy paste the full error message .

Comment: Have you tried to enclose all table and coloumn namens with ` ?